# Am I opening and closing my ODBC connection incorrectly?

Tags: .net, vb.net, odbc, sap-ase

When connecting to a Sybase ASE database via ODBC using the code below, I'll **occasionally** get a '[IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed' error.

Can this be caused by my code? I read [here](http://www.dbforums.com/asp/1049976-drivers-sqlsetconnectattr-failed.html) that I should be using the 'With' statement instead, but I don't understand how that would affect this.

Thanks in advance!

```
    Try
        odsConn.Open()
        Dim acctCheckString As String = sB.ToString
        Dim odsCmd As New OdbcCommand(acctCheckString, odsConn)

        odsRtrn = CStr(odsCmd.ExecuteScalar).TrimEnd
    Catch ex As Exception
        odsRtrn = ex.Message.ToUpper
        odsRtrn = CheckError(odsRtrn)
    Finally
        odsConn.Close()
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for interjecting without an answer to your specific question, but if I might make a suggestion...

In the year 2009, if you are using vb.Net, and you are still using ODBC, you should please (seriously) check out ADO.Net managed code data providers. There is one for Sybase...

[SyBase ADO.Net Providers](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-adonet/@Generic__CollectionView)

This will completely replace the odbc libraries. they are much easier to use.

Comment: Those look awesome, thanks. I'll see if I can convince my boss, but it may prove difficult :(

Comment: There is also third party driver from DataDirect... http://www.datadirect.com/products/net/net_for_sybase/index.ssp
I have not used any of these, (not a Sybase person) but I suggest you check them out

Comment: Yeah we looked at them originally, but they were a bit too expensive. Thanks again.